# Is there a way to create a meta box that can be added multiple times to a post dynamically?

Tags: posts, theme-development, customization, metabox

This shouldn't be that difficult (I wouldn't think) ... I just want to have a section of my theme (directors) that has the name of the director / their bio in the title and post respectively (done).

*But*, I would also like to have a meta-box on their post for their work (title / client / date / video link / thumb ) and I would like to be able to **add** or **remove** instances of this meta box as needed ... i.e. director A) has 3 videos ... director B) has 5 videos.

How do I create a meta box (or is there something else in WP) that can be dynamically added / removed (like the way the menu system works) where I have a menu and I can add as many or as few items to the menu as i want / need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPAlchemy are also useful, that could be customizable depend on your desire, But as Matthias Lehming said, Advanced customer fields are also good and quick staff to use.

Comment: This answer lead me to my solution (I discovered what I was looking for is called a 'repeatable field' through googling WPAlchemy) which in turn lead me to to this tuts+ tutorial http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields/ (in case anyone else needs the solution and wants to do it themselves)

Answer (score 1):

I've done such things often with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and the (fee-based) [Repeater Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) add-on. In my case, it was totally worth its money.

Comment: Except I'm not after a plugin, I'm building out a theme and want this functionality added in.